# If O(log n) vs O(n) is exponential what is O(1) vs O(n)?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology

If one refers to using an `O(log n)` instead of an `O(n)` algorithm as an exponential speedup, 
how would one refer the speedup gained by using an `O(1)` algorithm vs an `O(n)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no name for that, but the closest would be "infinite" speedup. $O(\log n)$ is considered an exponential speedup over $O(n)$, because $n$ *is exponential in* $\log n$: if we take the exponential function $f(n)=2^n$, we get $f(\log n)=2^{\log n}=n$.

However, $n$ *isn't anything in* $1$: there's no way to recover $n$ from $1$, no matter how quickly the function $f$ that we take grows, $f(1)$ will always be a constant (and never equal $n$). As $n\to \infty$, $1$ becomes infinitely smaller than $n$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this definition?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your confusion seems to be related to the technical meaning of the word "exponential".

As the definition is given in http://www.learnersdictionary.com, it is defined as:

> Exponential growth is literally growth that becomes faster and faster as it continues. In ordinary use, however, exponential is understood to mean simply “very fast” when it is used with words like growth and increase.

Now, let's consider an example, where n = 256 (a power of 2 for the sake of simplicity).
If n = 256, then \log_2 n = 8. This is an "exponential" speedup, because of the log function.

As far as O(1) is concerned, you need to realize that \log_n n = 1 in general. With that being said, O(1) will also be an ideal "exponential" speedup.

Hope this makes things clear.